# load_and_authorize_resource null cancancan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancancan

I'm attempting to load a resource using cancancan but it keeps returning null and I'm not sure why.
Could someone point out my error? I've attempted to do some debugging in the rails console to ensure the association conditions would return true in some cases, and in my test case, all the characters (2) belong to the user.

```
 Character.all.each {|char| puts user.characters.include? char }
  Character Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "characters".* FROM "characters"
true
true
```

Here's the code

api/v1/characters_controller.rb

```
module Api
  module V1
    class CharactersController < ApplicationController
      load_and_authorize_resource

      def index
        render json: @characters
      end

      ...
```

models/ability.rb

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    # Define abilities for the passed in user here. For example:
    #
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
    can :create, User

    if User.exists?(user)
      can :create, ApiKey
      can [:read, :destroy], Character do |character|
        user.characters.include? character
      end
    end
  end
end
```

response

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Etag: "37a6259cc0c1dae299a7866489dff0bd"
Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
X-Request-Id: f7102bb1-1928-4ef4-a459-2e9d62c5cdaf
X-Runtime: 5.110437
Server: WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.1.2/2014-05-08)
Date: Tue, 09 Dec 2014 15:28:18 GMT
Content-Length: 4
Connection: close

null
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
load_and_authorize_resource :character, parent: false
```

Details you can read here http://www.rubydoc.info/github/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/CanCan/ControllerAdditions/ClassMethods:load_resource